# Exporting hundreds of thousands of records with ColdFusion

Tags: sql, excel, coldfusion, export-to-excel, coldfusion-9

Using ColdFusion 9.0.1, I need to export hundreds of thousands of database records to Excel XLSX or CSV (XLSX is preferred). This must be done on demand. So far I've tried using cfspreadsheet but it chokes when exporting more than a couple thousand rows in the XLSX format. However, exporting to XLS works fine (of course there is a ~65,000 row limit).

What are my options to export so many records? Theoretically the users could need to export as many as one million records. I'm also using SQL Server 2008 R2 -- is there a way to somehow export the records to a file there and then send the file through CF to the user? What options do I have? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a DTS task in SQL and call it with CF, sleep for a few seconds and then make the file available for download through CF.

Comment: DTS is deprecated in SQL Server 2008. It's been replaced by SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). What you're recommending, though, can also be achieved in SSIS.

Comment: So Excel 2007 XLSX format allows for larger files (millions of rows), but appears to need significant memory to do so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921(v=office.12).aspx#Office2007excelPerf_BigGridIncreasedLimitsExcel

Comment: @eapen How would I get the file to CF once it is created by SQL Server?

Comment: @orangepips Ah, that makes sense as to why XLS worked ok but not XLSX. Thanks.

Comment: @dustin Easiest would be to have SQL server create the file in your web folder and then use CF to check if the file exists and show the link if the file exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you could take advantage of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and create a report that can be called via web service (or HTTP GET/POST) by ColdFusion.  SSRS has the capability to export reports as Excel as well. You'll need to read up on SSRS to make this work, but it's fairly easy to do.

Comment: Do you know if SSRS can stream out large volumes of data as the question asks? Or will it run into similar memory constraints?

Comment: Actually, SSRS 2008 will only export to XLS, not XLSX, so you're still limited to 65k rows per sheet in an XLS file.  You can, however use SSRS to generate a CSV with no 65k row limit.

That said, SSRS is more efficient at rendering XLS than is POI (the Java library used by ColdFusion for creating XLS files). I don't know that the output is streamed, but anecdotally, the memory footprint is much smaller when I've used SSRS over the same reports generated with POI/ColdFusion.

Comment: +1 BTW for doing from SQL Server. I've done this before with it, but not on the volume of data being described.

Comment: Do you know if 2008 R2 will export to XLSX? Note: Not just 2008, 2008 R2.

Comment: Unfortunately XLSX still isn't supported in R2. From the SQL Server Team:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/87cfd5d4-ea3c-4250-aab8-a1a3dffa3241

Answer (score 4):

As you've discovered, doing this with ColdFusion's `<cfspreadsheet/>` tag fails because it builds the entire document in memory, which leads to JVM OutOfMemory errors. What you need is something that buffers output to disk so you don't run out of memory. This suggests CSV, which is far easier to buffer. I imagine there are ways to do it with Excel as well, but I don't know them.

So two options for you:

1. use a Java library
2. use ColdFusion's `fileOpen()`, `fileWrite()`, `fileClose()` methods

I'll cover each in turn.

### Java Libary

[opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is my preference. This assumes of course you know how to setup a .jar on the ColdFusion classpath. If you do then it's a matter using its APIs to open a file and specify data for each line. It's really quite simple. Check its docs for examples.

### ColdFusion Methods

***Be forewarned there be dragons here***.

If you are exporting numbers or strings that do not contain any double quotes or commas you can probably do this. If not, figuring out what to escape and how is why you use a library in the first place. Code is roughly as such:

```
<!--- query to get whatever data you're working with --->

<cfset csvFile = fileOpen(filePath, 'read')>
<cfloop query="yourQuery">
    <cfset csvRow = ""><!--- construct a csv row here from the query row --->
    <cfset fileWrite(csvFile, csvRow)>
</cfloop>

<cfset fileClose(csvFile)>
```

If the query data you're working with is also large you may be dealing with a nested loop to chunk it out.

Comment: How do you chunk out the data from sql server to begin with. Does it return all 1 million rows to coldfusion? What I'm wondering is there a way to specify a batch size in cfquery and get the data in chunks.

Comment: @KobbyPemson: paging over data in SQL Server uses the function `ROW_NUMBER([ORDER BY CLAUSE])` - see the following link for an example: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm

Answer (score 0):

Dustin, I had to investigate this myself, and as of this writing (Summer 2011), POI does a fine job of generating large files, but you have to use xlsx. The 3.8 beta source ships with an example named "BigGridDemo" which generates a 100K, 4-column workbook very quickly. I modified it to generate 300K, 125-column sheet, and it handled it in about 2 minutes. It created a 1.6 GB, 3.6-million-row workbook in a little over half an hour.

Granted, the code isn't the prettiest to look at, but it works. I suspect it'll pretty up a bit when ported to ColdFusion.